# An extra column appearing in my .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a file named export .py and the code looks like this (I am learning how to use pandas)

```py
import pandas as pd

dict = {"country": ["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
       "capital": ["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Dehli", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
       "area": [8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
       "population": [200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }

brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)
brics.index = ["BR", "RU", "IN", "CH", "SA"]
print(brics)
print()
print()
print("Exporting as .csv file...")
export_csv = brics.to_csv ('/some/path/to/file/panda.csv', index=True, header=True)
print("Done!")
```

and another file, import.py:

```py
import pandas as pd
brics = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file/panda.csv")
print(brics)
```

and the outputs are:

```py
#export.py
         country    capital    area  population
BR        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
RU        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
IN         India  New Dehli   3.286     1252.00
CH         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
SA  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98


Exporting as .csv file...
Done!

#import.py
  Unnamed: 0       country    capital    area  population
0         BR        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
1         RU        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
2         IN         India  New Dehli   3.286     1252.00
3         CH         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
4         SA  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98
```

Can anyone tell me how to clean the table up so the two outputs look the same (removing the "0, 1, 2, 3..." indexes)?

Comment: in `import.py` put `pd.read_csv("/path/to/file/panda.csv",index_col=0)`